# C# Linq XML Query where multiple elements of same name exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Linq newbie here. Did the searching, and couldn't find an exact question; tried to work from other answers that were *similar*, but still couldn't get it.

Having trouble returning all instances of a particular element name. I can get one item returned, just not them all.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<printerlist>
  <list type="aff">
    <printserver>print-server1</printserver>
    <printserver>print-server2</printserver>
    <printserver>print-server3</printserver>
  </list>
  <list type="lff">
    <printserver>print-sever4</printserver>
    <additionalprinters>
      <printer>
        <fullname>\\serverb\bbb</fullname>
      </printer>
      <printer>
        <fullname>\\serverc\aaa</fullname>
      </printer>
    </additionalprinters>
  </list>
</printerlist>
```

And here is the code to try and get the list:

```
var query = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("list")
    where (string)c.Attribute("type") == "aff"
    select c.Element("printserver");

foreach (string name in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server Name: {0}", name);
}
```

This only produces the first element of printserver: **print-server1**
How can I get the foreach to list all 3 servers that are in the *aff* list?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps because you are using c.Element instead of c.Elements? I don't have access to a compiler to test this just now.

Comment: Hi, both comments above do not work when superimposed directly onto the existing code. They may work with a little more massaging.... but thanks for the input, has been answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Elements("printserver")` instead of `Element("printserver")` like so :

```
var query = (from c in doc.Root.Descendants("list").Elements("printserver")
             where (string)c.Parent.Attribute("type") == "aff"
             select c);
```

or using `SelectMany()` like this :

```
var query = (from c in doc.Root.Descendants("list")
             where (string)c.Attribute("type") == "aff"
             select c).SelectMany(c => c.Elements("printserver"));
```

or if you are sure only one element match the `where` clause, you can use `First()` like this :

```
var query = (from c in doc.Root.Descendants("list")
             where (string)c.Attribute("type") == "aff"
             select c).First().Elements("printserver"));
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this works and is not too far off my original code using traditional query. It's interesting to see the different ways that this can be achieved. One way may prove better than another when I expand on my queries at a later date.

Comment: Updated my answer with another possible way. Glad to know this answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
List<XElement> elements = doc.Root.Descendants("printserver")
                                 .Where(e => e.Parent.Name == "list" && e.Parent.Attribute("type").Value == "aff")
                                 .ToList();
```

Then, if you want to loop through the elements:

```
foreach (XElement e in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server Name : {0}", e.Value);
}
```

If you just want the string-values of each printserver, use a .Select at the end:

```
List<string> elements = doc.Root.Descendants("printserver")
                                .Where(e => e.Parent.Name == "list" && e.Parent.Attribute("type").Value == "aff")
                                .Select(p => p.Value)
                                .ToList();
```

Above solution allows the use of your current foreach-loop.

Comment: Hi. This works perfectly too... but I can only choose one answer. In my case, I was trying to use LINQ with the traditional query notation (rather than Lambda, which is the answer you provided if I understand correctly)... and as I am still getting used to LINQ I thought I would mark the tradition as my answer. But thank you - I will be looking at the differences between the two.

Comment: @MrBeatnik: Sure, no problem! LINQ and Lambda are often used togheter. If you're interested in learning more about the two, read here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33769/Basics-of-LINQ-Lamda-Expressions